# Javascript - define variables in a JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a project based in Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8 deployed on a WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.2.0.0
I have this code in my JSP

```
<script src="${contextPath}/scripts/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript">

var optionsEUCountriesArray = [];
var optionsNonEUCountriesArray = [];

<c:forEach items="${countries}" var="country" varStatus="status">
    var option${country.id} = new Option("${country.id}","${country.description}");
    <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${country.euMember}">
        optionsArray.push(option${country.id});  
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${not country.euMember}">
        optionsArray.push(option${country.id});
    </c:when>       
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
</script>

<script src="${contextPath}/scripts/selectbox.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Inside the `selectbox.js` I use the variable `optionsEUCountriesArray` , but I got this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: optionsEUCountriesArray is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are combining scripts. probably this should solve your problem..

```
 <script src="${contextPath}/scripts/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script>

var optionsEUCountriesArray = [];
var optionsNonEUCountriesArray = [];
<c:forEach items="${countries}" var="country" varStatus="status">
    var option${country.id} = new Option("${country.id}","${country.description}");
    <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${country.euMember}">
        optionsArray.push(option${country.id});  
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${not country.euMember}">
        optionsArray.push(option${country.id});
    </c:when>       
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
</script>
```

Comment: after this call your selectbox.js